# Avoid specifying domain at logon?

Tags: authentication, active-directory

Is it possible to configure Sharepoint 2010 (or maybe IIS) to automatically assume a logon domain during authentication?

We have a pretty long domain name and would like to alleviate the user from having to type the [domain]\ before their username all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to avoid that is to not use Integrated Authentication in IIS.

By doing that, you can specify the domain and users can just type in their credentials.  But to me this is a big draw back to Windows/IE users that can configure automatic passing of credentials and never be prompted for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If the users are in the same domain as the web server, I didn't think that they had to supply the domain, and that the domain was automatically inferred